# Python parallel encryption of many photos

Tags: python, multithreading, cryptography, multiprocessing

I'm working on a school project. I want to encrypt a large collection of photos ( millions of them ) with AES. I'd like to run the encryptions in pararell.

My I/O for the encrypted photos seems very slow. I have just one read and one write for every photo.

I'm using the cryptography module from python 3.7 .

What can I do to get better I/O write speeds ?

I tried Multithreading and Multiprocessing. They both gave me similar results ( sometimes they even seem to be slower than the sync one )

Update :
Here is my code

```
import os
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import time
import multiprocessing
import threading
    
key = b"\xb2f\xff$j1\xc9\xec\x12\xa09\xa7\x7f\x16B\x93\x97~:\x9f\x1d\x1f\x907\x1c'\x0f\xf6A\xf5jf"
backend = default_backend()

def write(file, data ) : 
    with open( file, "wb", 6000 ) as writer : 
        writer.write( data )
        writer.close()


def encrypt_unit( file ):
    padder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).padder()
    
    with open(file, "rb") as reader :
        data = reader.read()   
        reader.close()
        
    iv = os.urandom(16)
    data = padder.update(data) + padder.finalize()
    
    encryptor = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend).encryptor()
    message = encryptor.update(data) + encryptor.finalize()

    write( file, iv + message )

def decrypt_unit( file ):

    padder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).unpadder()

    with open(file, "rb") as reader :
        data = reader.read()   
        reader.close()
    
    iv = data[:16]
    data = data[16:]
    
    decryptor = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend).decryptor()
    message = decryptor.update(data) + decryptor.finalize()
    
    
    message = padder.update(message) + padder.finalize()
    
    write( file, message )

def big_task( shouldEncrypt, file_list ) :
    for f in file_list :
        if shouldEncrypt : 
            encrypt_unit( f )
        else :
            decrypt_unit( f )

try : 
    
    path = "/home/codaruuu/Desktop/test"
    file_list = os.listdir(path)
    file_list = [ path + "/" + bit for bit in file_list if bit.endswith(".jpeg") ]
    
    N = 4
    M = len( file_list )
    PrList = []
    
    for i in range(N) :
        pr = multiprocessing.Process(
            target=big_task,
            args=(True, file_list[ (M // N ) * i : (M // N ) * ( i + 1 ) ] )
        )
        PrList.append( pr )
        pr.start()
        
    for pr in PrList :
        pr.join()
    
    
except Exception as err :
    print( err )
```

Comment: You should post some code. I'm skeptical that multithreading and multiprocessing are slower for millions of photos, so you may not be using the libraries in the correct manner.

Comment: Is the issue the file io speed, or is it the cpu time being taken for the encryption? Python has a global interpreter lock so if these encryption jobs are cpu bound then multithreading won't help. But multiprocessing should have shown a difference

Answer (score 1):

The first thing I observed is that you are not correctly splitting up your file list:

```py
file_list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k']
N = 4
M = len(file_list)
for i in range(N) :
    print(file_list[ (M // N ) * i : (M // N ) * ( i + 1 ) ] )
```

Prints:

```
['a', 'b']
['c', 'd']
['f', 'g']
['h', 'i']
```

But if you want maximum efficiency, you should be using as many CPU cores that you have and distributing the CPU-intensive work among them. The easiest way to do that is to use a multiprocessing pool. There may also be a slight performance improvement to be gained if you are dealing with lots of files if we can segregate the pure I/O from the pure CPU and use both a thread pool and a multiprocessing pool, the former being used for the I/O and the latter, which is passed to the threaded worker function to be used for the CPU-intensive calculation. In this way we *might* get better I/O overlap. It all depends on the type of drive you have. I have allocated all the CPU cores to the multiprocessing pool. You could try holding back one core, i.e. allocating `os.cpu_count() - 1` to ensure that the I/O always has a core to run on.

**Update**

If the number of files you will be dealing with are really in the millions, then perhaps it would be better not to construct `file_list` as a list of such a size. Likewise, the `map` function will return a list of results (all `None` values since your worker functions `encrypt_unit` and `decrypt_unit` implicitly return `None`) whose length will also be in the millions. It would be better then to use generator functions for both of these:

```py
import os
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import padding
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.ciphers import Cipher, algorithms, modes
from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
import time
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
from functools import partial
from pathlib import Path


key = b"\xb2f\xff$j1\xc9\xec\x12\xa09\xa7\x7f\x16B\x93\x97~:\x9f\x1d\x1f\x907\x1c'\x0f\xf6A\xf5jf"
backend = default_backend()

def write(path, data ) :
    with path.open("wb") as writer:
        writer.write( data )

def encrypt_data(data):
    padder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).padder()
    iv = os.urandom(16)
    data = padder.update(data) + padder.finalize()

    encryptor = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend).encryptor()
    message = encryptor.update(data) + encryptor.finalize()
    return message

def encrypt_unit(processing_pool, path):
    with path.open("rb") as reader:
        data = reader.read()
    encrypted_data = processing_pool.apply(encrypt_data, args=(data,))
    write(file, encrypted_data)

def decrypt_data(encrypted_data):
    padder = padding.PKCS7(algorithms.AES.block_size).unpadder()
    iv = encrypted_data[:16]
    encrypted_data = encrypted_data[16:]

    decryptor = Cipher(algorithms.AES(key), modes.CBC(iv), backend).decryptor()
    message = decryptor.update(encrypted_data) + decryptor.finalize()
    message = padder.update(message) + padder.finalize()
    return message

def decrypt_unit(processing_pool, path):
    with path.open("rb") as reader:
        encrypted_data = reader.read()
    message = processing_pool.apply(decrypt_data, args=(encrypted_data,))
    write(path, message)

def compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size):
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize

try :

    path = "/home/codaruuu/Desktop/test"
    file_list = Path(path).glob('*.jpeg')
    # Estimate of file_list length
    # (to get exact length would require converting file_list to an actual list, which we want to avoid)
    # for testing with small lists, just set this to 1:
    FILE_LIST_SIZE = 1_000_000

    # If the files are large and/or memory is scarce reduce this number:
    N_THREADS = 100 # Your guess is as good as mine
    N_PROCESSES = os.cpu_count() # number of cores
    SHOULD_ENCRYPT = True

    processing_pool = Pool(N_PROCESSES)
    thread_pool = ThreadPool(N_THREADS)
    worker = partial(encrypt_unit, processing_pool) if SHOULD_ENCRYPT else partial(decrypt_unit, processing_pool)
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(FILE_LIST_SIZE, N_THREADS)
    for result in thread_pool.imap_unordered(worker, file_list, chunksize):
        pass

except Exception as err :
    print( err )
```